# Create a variable with custom name and assigning it an object DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to rename the name of the DataFrame with a name containing a variable.

```
rename = 'test'

df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [2, 4, 8, 0]})

f'df_{rename}' = df
```

But I get the following error message: "SyntaxError: can't assign to literal"

What I exepct as an output : **df_test** instead of df

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: To be able to easily change the dataframe name in the global variables

Comment: It is theoretically possible to do what you show by use of `globals()` but there is almost certainly a better way to do this. And if you show here how you intend to **use** that variable once you have renamed it, then hopefully somebody will be able to suggest to you how else you might access it (almost certainly as a dictionary lookup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR : Use your own custom dictionary with the variable name as it's key - is the best practice.

***What You Asked For***

You can create a variable with a custom name by adding it to the [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd

rename = 'test'

df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [2, 4, 8, 0]})

# Creating a variable with a custom name by adding it to globals
globals()[f'df_{rename}'] = df

print(df_test)
```

***How To Have a Variable With Custom Name - According to Best-Practices***

Use your own dictionary to keep up with your custom variables.

```
import pandas as pd

rename = 'test'

df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [2, 4, 8, 0]})

# Creating a custom dictionary for the custom variables
my_dataframes                       = dict()
custom_variable_name                = 'df_{rename}'
my_dataframes[custom_variable_name] = df

print(my_dataframes[custom_variable_name])
```

Comment: thank you is exactly what I wanted. I didn't think it was that unintuitive.

Comment: Glad it helped! @Laurent

Comment: @Laurent Do not use this. Use a dictionary. (By which I mean, your own dictionary, not globals.)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables